# Mail SMTP server list discrepancy

Tags: macos, mail.app, smtp

When I'm in Accounts and I select the dropdown of SMTP servers I get a long list of servers (as I manage a lot of accounts). But when I go to edit the SMTP server list, not all of the accounts in the dropdown are listed. Any ideas what's happening?

Answer (score 2):

Finally found out what the issue is. Half the accounts on the Account dropdown under SMTP are from the Internet Accounts under System Settings > Accounts, not just your SMTP server settings list. Its really confusing.

Comment: Good find. Are the ones not entered in mail.app shown grayed out, or just it took some digging to understand what’s happening in mail.app?